# blazor server blocks ui while executing a long-running async task

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server application where a button click executes a relatively long running task. something like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=KickOffLongRunningTask>Generate Report</button>

 private async Task KickOffLongRunningTask()
        {
            try
            {                
                await Spinner.Display();              

                Model = await _service.GenerateReport();               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Log(ex);
            }
            finally
            {                
                await Spinner.Hide();
            }
        }
```

the service exposes an event to which i subscribe - the event reports progress (percent of data processed).

```
event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> PercentComplete;
```

the event subscription works fine and the progress is displayed on the page as it is reported - so the UI representation of the progress works fine.

However, at the same time - no button events work. neither does link navigation - so all user actions are "frozen".

cant figure out why. any bright ideas are welcome.